# Fill irreguar grid points

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, pattern-matching, signal-processing

So I have a set of an incomplete set of 2d points following a certain pattern.

[image]

You can see in the example image that some points are missing. I tried to fit a grid but I find that although the points seem to be arranged in a  straight line there can be a slight deviation. I tried to find an algorithm that fills the rest of the image with dots but I did not find any. I tried to estimate the horizontal and vertical frequency of the dots using FFT but the frequency also tends to vary a bit.

Is there any obvious algorithm I am missing here that can solve this problem?

Comment: Scattered interpolation is the keyword to search for

Comment: Looks promising! Thanks for the keyword. I will read up on it and report back later how it works.

Comment: @Trilarion as far as I understand Scattered interpolation interpolates the data sampled at specific points from a signal. So it would work if I had an underlying image that I can sample the "white dots" and I wanted to interpolate the sampled value across the image. That is not what I want to do. I simply want to fill the image with the missing white dots. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

You can treat this like a 2D point cloud problem, and use tessellation as one way to fill the gaps. The tricky bit that still requires a good solution is to decide what is a hole and what isn't. Here I've implemented a naive triangle area based method to decide. You can fine-tune the area threshold value to improve it or figure out another way.

[image]

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

gray     = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh   = cv2.threshold( gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1]
contours = cv2.findContours( thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

def get_center( rect ):
    x,y,w,h = rect
    return np.array([x+w/2, y+h/2])

points, points_orig = [np.array([ get_center(cv2.boundingRect(c)) for c in contours[1] ])]*2
points[:,1] = im.shape[0] - points[:,1] # Flip Y to plot correctly without image

# Use Delaunay triangulation to calculate triangles from points
tri   = Delaunay(points)
tris  = np.array([ points[i] for i in tri.simplices ]) # Get arrays of coordinates
areas = np.array([ cv2.contourArea(np.array([t]).astype('int')) for t in tris ])

thresh = np.mean( areas ) # Set area threshold to mean triangle area

f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20,20))

for ax, t in zip(axs.flat, ['Original Points', 'Tesselated', 'Holes', 'Mesh without holes']):
    ax.scatter( points[:,0], points[:,1], color='red', zorder=2 )
    ax.set_facecolor('black')
    ax.set_title( t, color='white')
    ax.axis('off')
    
for ax in axs.flat[1:]:
    ax.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices, zorder=1, color='gray')

masks = [ areas > thresh, areas <= thresh ]
for ax, mask, color in zip(axs[1], masks, ['cornflowerblue', 'indianred']):
    plottris = tris[ mask ]
    for t in plottris:
        p = Polygon(t, facecolor=color, edgecolor=None, zorder=0)
        ax.add_patch(p)

f.set_facecolor('black')
plt.show()
```